# Is there any HTTP library in R?

Tags: r

I need to make HTTP POST commands using R. Are there any R http libraries that can do this?

Comment: [httr] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493767/rcurl-with-http-data-post

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, [RCurl](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html)

```
library(RCurl)
# example from the vignette:
x = postForm('http://www.wormbase.org/db/searches/advanced/dumper', 
  species="briggsae", 
  list="", 
  flank3="0", 
  flank5="0", 
  feature="Gene Models", 
  dump = "Plain TEXT", 
  orientation = "Relative to feature", 
  relative = "Chromsome", 
  DNA ="flanking sequences only", 
  .cgifields =c("feature", "orientation", "DNA", "dump", "relative"))
```

If you want fine-grained control over the posted entity and headers, you can use `curlPerform` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative that may be more convenient to use is [httr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=httr):

> Useful tools for working with HTTP organised by HTTP verbs (GET(),
>   POST(), etc). Configuration functions make it easy to control
>   additional request components (authenticate(), add_headers() and so
>   on).