# Rcurl with http data post

Tags: r, rcurl

I would like to move the following curl call to Rcurl:

```
curl  'http://myserver.org/stream' 
-H 'Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXX' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data-binary '{"limit": 20}' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8'
```

This is one of my R tests:

```
library(RCurl)
url.opts <- list(httpheader = list(Authorization ="Basic XXXXXXXX", 
                Connection = "keep-alive", 
                "Content-Type" = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"))

getURLContent('http://myserver.org/stream', .opts=url.opts)
```

Now I am missing an attribute to add --data or --data-binary. How to add this option?

Thanks a lot
Markus

Comment: You can use `getURLContent(..., customrequest = 'POST', postfields = '{"limit": 20}')` or something similar.

Comment: It might be a bit easier with `httr`: `POST('http://myserver.org/stream', c(authenticate(u, p, "basic"), accept_json(), body = '{"limit": 20}')`

Answer (score 4):

Thanks a lot @hadley.

This is my working solution:

```
library(httr)
user <- "test"
password <- "test123"
POST(url = 'http://myserver.org/stream', 
     config = c(authenticate(user, password, "basic"), 
                add_headers(Connection = "keep-alive"), 
                accept_json()), 
     body = "{'username':'test'}")
```